# Boundary conditions for 2D helical waveguide

Tags: electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, waves, differential-equations

I'm interested in looking at standing wave solutions for the wave equation on a 2D annulus, with the twist that the annulus is "streched" in to a helix in 3D, but so that the rings themselves are 2-dimensional. For the wave equation in polar coordinates, it seems straightforward enough to extend the azimuthal boundary conditions to angles larger than $2\pi$, and the radial component would be similar to the regular 2 dimensional case.

However, I'm having difficulty formulating the boundary conditions for the $z$ direction, to enforce the fact that this helix is "stretched out" vertically in space and that there is some separation distance between the turns on the helix, but so that the waves themselves are confined to the 2D surface.  Is there a good method to go about enforcing this condition that might lead to an analytic solution?

Comment: Check out [H. G. Unger, "Helix Waveguide Theory and Application"](http://www3.alcatel-lucent.com/bstj/vol37-1958/articles/bstj37-6-1599.pdf) and [Z. Menachem and M. Haridim, "Propagation in a helical waveguide with inhomogeneous dielectric profiles in rectangular cross section", Progress In Electromagnetics Research B, Vol. **16**, pp155-188, 2009](http://www.jpier.org/PIERB/pierb16/07.09022202.pdf)

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Nice references, thanks!

Comment: My PhD supervisor did a bit of work on this back in the 60s, so I know there is a lot of stuff around on this. I was heartily surprised to see the 2009 reference. I think people were thinking hard about waveguides with low loss in the days before optical fibres - which had been thought of but everyone thought that achieving their theoretical low loss might be impracticable. Indeed, they are only low loss by dint of a huge amount of materials engineering to achieve what they theoretically can) and for some reason (which I can't recall), people thought the Floquet modes of the periodic ....

Comment: ... helical structure would be low loss. There were some wild ideas about how future communication networks would look. IBM foresaw a network of extremely highly engineered copper waveguides underground like a sewage network (and of not too different dimensions BTW) with ridiculous smoothness and bend specifications to achieve their astronomical few megabit per second transmission rates. The Unger paper reminded me of this idea and I think maybe it might have been related to coming up with a "high bandwidth sewage pipe waveguide" that wouldn't have the ridiculous surface smoothness ....

Comment: ... specifications. The original optical fibres being played with at this time were liquid core ones.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Wow, that's interesting.  Do you have any references from that time period detailing these plans? It would make a really interesting read.  Thanks again for the references on the helical waveguides - the math seems fairly involved so I will have to do some review of EM topics before I can fully understand them.

Comment: I just sent an email to my PhD supervisor - it would be good to recall the exact references for this interesting bit of history. What is you interest in helical waveguides, BTW?